# sql server 2012 create temporary view on stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to create a view (temporary )on procedure.
Possible mean it make overload  on database.

please suggest me and is anyother way to do.

My need is merging all table to make pdf file based on condition.

```
create procedure sp1
as
begin

create view temp_view as (select * from tabl_1
        union all
        select * from tabl_2
        union all
        select * from tabl_3
        union all
        select * from tabl_4
        union all
        select * from tabl_5
        union all
        select * from tabl_6
        union all
        select * from tabl_7
        union all
        select * from tabl_8)cte;
select col1,col2,col3 from temp_view where col1=val;
drop view temp_view;
end
```

Comment: 1) create a view 2) then use that view inside the SP

Comment: What is the reason you want to create a view with all tables merged? There are other ways to create backups of databases!

Comment: too make pdf report based on condition @cfi

Comment: is it possible to create view inside sp then drop it. @ tinka

Comment: Using Dynamic SQL you can create dynamically views inside stored procedure like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32194886/5070879)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps(without creating a view):

1. Create a cache table to store all the records from these tables
2. create a job(SP) or trigger to populate the cache table in a regular interval(say 10 mins) 
3. use the cache table in the report SP. It will always give you the updated report

Comment: which means cache table occupies memory . but in rare case only i need to call that view.

Comment: Actually i'm new to ms sql server. i think ur answer is create sp1 to generate #cahe_tbl table and set time limit for #cahe_tbl table. then create sp2  step 1-> call sp1,  step -> 2 select #cahe_tbl . right?

Comment: if its rare case only then you can directly use the query, no need to change it.

Comment: sorry not care case .we access frequently.every table contais more records totally upto 40000 .

Comment: can u pls say how to create cache table

Comment: cache table is like normal table. You need a script to populate it only.

Comment: See: https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-performance/sql-server-temporary-object-caching for more on temporary object caching mentioned above.